# Iterate dynamic nested form controls Angular 2

Tags: forms, angular, loops

I have the following structure and wish to display the OPTIONS accordingly inside my HTML template.

```js
{
  "values": {
    "defaultValue": "something",
    "options": {
      "0": {
        "key": "Foo",
        "value": "Hotel"
      },
      "1": {
        "key": "Bar",
        "value": "foz"
      },
      "2": {
        "key": "appel",
        "value": "kaas"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I've created this seperate `MultiValue.component.ts`:

```ts
import {Component, Input} from "@angular/core";
import {FormGroup, FormArray, FormControl, Validators} from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
    selector: 'multi-value',
    templateUrl: 'multi-value.component.html'
})
export class MultiValueComponent {
    @Input('group')
    public multiValueForm: FormGroup;

    protected addMultiValueControl(): void {
        let options = <FormArray>this.multiValueForm.controls['options'];
        let option = new FormGroup({
            'key': new FormControl('', [<any>Validators.required]),
            'value': new FormControl('', [<any>Validators.required])
        });
        options.push(option);
    }
}
```

My template is the following:

```html
<div class="form" [formGroup]="multiValueForm">
    <div *ngFor="let option of multiValueForm.controls.options.controls; let i=index">
        <div class="form-group" [formGroupName]="i">
            <h1 class="control-label">Index: {{ i + 1 }}</h1>
            <label>Key: <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="key"></label>
            <label>Value: <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="value"></label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I call the component by referencing my form as follows:

```html
<multi-value [group]="newElementForm.controls.values"></multi-value>
```

When I debug inside the `MultiValueComponent` I can confirm that `public multiValueForm: FormGroup;` really contains the `FormArray` options.

Now I tried a lot of different setups in my template, but the truth is that I cannot seem to get this to work. All documentation states this should work but I have got no idea why it doesn't.

The error I now get is:

```
EXCEPTION: Error in ./MultiValueComponent class MultiValueComponent - inline template:2:32 caused by: Cannot find control with unspecified name attribute
```

Previous errors were resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you handle the adding of formgroups inside your formarray with the parent and just pass the nested formgroup to the child and fine with that. I have found that error seems to be thrown unless you do this. Here's a shortened code of yours, using `FormBuilder` being injected in constructor.

So in your parent the build of the form should look something like this:

```ts
ngOnInit() {
  this.newElementForm = this.fb.group({
    multiValueForm: this.fb.group({
      options: this.fb.array([])
    })
  })
}
```

Then the adding of a new control:

```ts
addMultiValueControl() {
  let control = <FormArray>this.newElementForm.controls.multiValueForm.controls.options;
  control.push(this.fb.group({
    value: ['']
  }))
}
```

Then just pass the formGroup `multiValueForm`:

```html
<multi-value [group]="newElementForm.controls.multiValueForm"></multi-value>
```

Input in child, just like you have:

```ts
@Input('group')
multiValueForm: FormGroup
```

and your child template:

```html
<div [formGroup]="multiValueForm">
  <div formArrayName="options">
  <div *ngFor="let group of multiValueForm.controls.options.controls; let i=index">
    <div formGroupName= {{i}}>
      <label>Value: </label>
      <input formControlName="value">
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's a

### [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/QufiOL71OsuDG2lbRttJ?p=preview)

Comment: Your explanation is good to understand and the example is very helpful. I've found out that I actually was missing `<div formArrayName="options">` and was not correctly setting the `formGroupName="{{i}}"`.
Thank you for your help, I marked your answer as correct.

Comment: Okay great, thanks! Most important is that you solved your problem. Have a great day and happy coding :)

Comment: Well, I solved it by using your solution actually, so in terms: you solved it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The form controls are bound by name. Add `name` attribute to the input controls.

```html
<label>Key: <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="key" name="key"></label>
<label>Value: <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="value" name="value"></label>
```

Comment: This is not true with reactive forms, formcontrolname is enough.

Comment: @AJT_82 How can't you remove this message then `caused by: Cannot find control with unspecified name attribute`?

Comment: Can't answer that, more than there is always some error thrown when you are trying to manipulate the build of a model-driven form in the child. All tutorials I also seen, handle everything in the parent and just pass the nested group to the child, but it's an interesting question as to why this is. Hopefully someone smarter could answer this :P In tutorials there is also no explanation (can't provide any direct links now, since I don't have them bookmarked). But anyways, it's a fact that you shouldn't need need the name attribute in model-driven-forms.